# Is this a valid application of "separation of variables"?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67877/is-this-a-valid-derivation-of-the-legendre-transformation-from-the-euler-lagrang) over at Physics SE.  I am not satisfied with the answer.  At the heart of the question is this mathematical concern:

Can I invoke "separation of variables" to go from this:

$$\frac{d p}{dt}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$$

to this:

$$\frac{\partial q}{dt} dp=\partial L$$

And since $\frac{\partial q}{dt}$ looks kind of weird (what with the mixing of partial and full derivative notation), can I just call it $\frac{d q}{dt}$?

Comment: What you wrote does not even make sense to me. What $dp$ by itself? $\partial L$? Expressions like $dp/dt$ are a single atomic unit. You really can't split them up.

Comment: Math isn't symbol sleight of hand; it has to *make sense*.

Comment: To be fair, we *can* come up with a reasonable interpretation of $dp$ by itself. However, I have never seen $\partial q$ by itself (interpreting $\partial$ as partial derivative, not boundary), and to the best of my knowledge, there is no such object.